# simple openmp c++ problem when using for loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, openmp

This is a code for parallel compute Fibonacci sequence. I would like to know how it works during the Fibonacci series calculation. The calculation of the Fibonacci series requires the involvement of two previous values, how is it ensured in OpenMP that the two previous values must have been calculated? If they are not calculated then how does it work?

```cpp
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int N = 20;
int main()
{
    int i, tid;
    int a[N];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel shared(a) private(i, tid)
    {

#pragma omp for
        for (i = 2; i < N; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
            printf("i = %d, I am Thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
        }
            
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In addition to this, if I don't use a `printf` statement in the for loop, then this code runs correctly, but if I add the intermediate `printf` statement, the final calculation becomes
[image]

Comment: Hi @user23624033, welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking for book recommendations is against SO policy.

Comment: OpenMP does not check the parallelization is correct. This is your job, and you fail to do it. As a result, OpenMP can generate a bogus program with an undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you want to compute a specific number of the Fibonacci sequence, then there are a logarithmic version for that. This one is linear and it is algorithmically optimal for computing the N first terms of the sequence. That being said it can be made a bit faster with micro-optimization. There is no way to parallelize this loop (so this is not just an OpenMP issue).

Comment: By the way, using tuning the `OMP_NUM_THREADS`  environment variable is better than using `omp_set_num_threads`. The former is more flexible and the idiomatic way to tune the number of threads of an OpenMP program.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Textual output should be copied as text into a code block instead of wasting bandwidth with an image that also limits accessibility.

Comment: To add some more vocabulary: Your implementation contains a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software) on `a[i]` which causes non-deterministic output. Even if it looks like it works without the `printf`, you should not rely on that behavior. It could change when e.g. changing the build type/flags or the compiler/OpenMP implementation because it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,
This algorithm cannot just be parallelized by applying OpenMP pragmas.

As you already indicated in your question, the for i loop suffers from 'loop carried dependence': a[i-1] and a[i-2] need to be calculated before.

OpenMP does not have the magic to do such a thing.

Your printf() likely has a mutex inside, effectively killing the parallelization.

Comment: Note however that if `printf` was actually killing the parallelization, then the result would be correct!

Comment: Well, if the pragma is "task" and you use task dependencies it might work. But yeah. This is largely sequential.

Comment: @PierU, indeed, I need to be more precise. It might first calculate the wrong values, based on not-yet-calculated a[earlier iterations], then it will sequentialize the output.